# Open specific App screens (like deep link) through Google assistant

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I am just getting started with integration of Google Assistant in Android App. Is it possible to achieve deep linking like functionality in android app through Google Assistant.

So in other words if we utter specific words in Google Assistant & it responds by opening specific activity inside my android app.

I have a news application & I want to have a feature in which user asks for specific type of news through Google Assistant, app should respond by launching specific activity containing news.

Thanks

Comment: Any updates on this?